# AS3 "IF" statement, within a For statement, to control movieclip within movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a movieclip on the screen called "mc_bg". Within this movieclip are 7 movieclips called "barrier1" through "barrier7".

From main.as I want to be able to do this call:

```
for (var i: int = 1; i < 3; i++ ){
    trace("got here")
    trace(mc_bg["mc_barrier" + String(i)])
    if(mc_bg["mc_barrier"+String(i)].hitTestObject(hurdlePerson)){
        trace("Test "+(i))
    }
}
```

I think there is an issue with my if statement.

hurdlePerson is the character. If I do:

`mc_bg.mc_barrier1.hitTestObject(hurdlePerson)`

It works.

What am I missing here to make this work?
I don't want to have to type out the multiple hitTestObject's which is what I currently have to do.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: So, just to confirm, mc_bg is a child of main.as, and the mc_barrier MovieClips are children of mc_bg? What does your `trace(mc_bg["mc_barrier"+i])` code trace out? Is hurdlePerson a child of main.as? Does replacing the for loop *in the same spot* with your alternate, hardcoded line work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) what is the output of your code, What traces u get?

2) trace to see if those movies created and available

3) try with parent

```
        if(parent.mc_bg["mc_barrier"+i].hitTestObject(hurdlePerson))
        {
            trace("Test "+i)
        }
```

Comment: got here
null
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at src::main/hurdleCollisionCheck()

--- The movies are on the stage and are there
--- Parent doesn't work

Comment: @KevinMcGowan: Could you post what the problem was? Just saying you fixed it does not help future visitors.

Comment: The code was correct, it was an issue on the actual movieclips with names.